# Computing the kernel of a certain linear map of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is my setup: let $A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $k$, and let $I,J$ be ideals of $A$. Since $A$ is Noetherian, $I$ is finitely generated, say by $r_1,\dots,r_m$, so there is a surjective map $A^m\to I$ given by taking $(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ to $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i r_i$. This is not a ring homomorphism (since multiplication probably doesn't work out nicely), but it is a $k$-linear map of $k$-vector spaces (or perhaps an $A$-module homomorphism, if you'd prefer). Now consider composing this with the canonical projection $I\to I/IJ$, which is also a $k$-linear map/$A$-module homomorphism (I think).

I'm trying to determine the kernel of the composition $A^m\to I\to I/IJ$. It definitely contains the ideal $J^m$, since $(j_1,\dots,j_m)$ (with the $j_i\in J$) gets taken to $\sum_{i=1}^m j_i r_i\in IJ$, which then gets modded out. But is it equal to this ideal? Or could the kernel be larger?

I think this is equivalent to asking whether a sum $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i r_i$ could be in $IJ$ even if none of the coefficients $a_i$ are in $J$. But I have not been able to get very far with this.

Comment: It is $J^n+\{(c_1,\dots,c_m)\in A^n\mid\sum c_ir_i=0\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on what Anne Bauval said:

$\phi: A^m \to I$, $\phi(a) = \sum_i a_i r_i$ and $\varphi : A^m \to I/IJ$.

$\phi$ is surjective: $\phi(A^m)=I$.

It is also compatible with the $A$-module structures: $$\phi(J^m) = \phi(J \cdot A^m) = J\cdot \phi(A^m) = IJ$$

It means that if $\varphi(a)=0$, which means $\phi(a)\in IJ$, then there is $b \in J^m$ such that $\phi(a+b)= 0$.

Therefore $$\ker(\varphi) = \ker(\phi) + J^m$$